# Headers are being sent although output already sent

Tags: php

For what I know is it is not possible to send HTTP headers after your output has been sent and only way to workaround is to use output buffering

But my PHP script is able to send headers even after output is sent.
here is my code

```
Text output already sent
<?php
header('Location: test2.php');
die();
?>
```

Why is this code not giving error for "HTTP headers already sent"
Is there another way to turn output buffering on?

EDIT:

I am running it on my localhost using wamp

No files are included in the above code

I just noticed outbut_buffering directive in phpinfo() which is set to 1
But when I check it in php.ini file it is set to Off

Comment: do you have output error enabled? is the redirect performed? (I doubt it)

Comment: Fact that error wasn't displayed doesn't mean that there was no error at all ;)

Comment: yes display_errors is set to On and the redirect is being performed

Answer (score 2):

You are right, this should not work.

First, are you sure the headers are written, or do you simply wonder why there is no error message shown? Maybe error reporting is turned off? In that case try to increase the error reporting level:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

*Remove this from your code when you're finished debugging. Errors should be logged to a log file and never be shown in productive environment!*

Also, check if the header is really sent. You can do that with `wget` for example:

```
wget -S http://example.com/
```

or `curl`:

```
curl -v http://example.com/
```

You can as well see the HTTP headers in Chromes developer console. In other browsers most probably too.

If the header is really sent, then there probably is some magic regarding output buffering in place. Are you running this locally or on a remote host? If this is not your host, it might be the provider has set this up. PHP has a feature to automatically prepend and append custom code. Check the `php.ini` settings for [auto_prepend_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file) and [auto_append_file](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file). There could be some `ob_start()` etc. hidden. You can see all PHP settings by calling [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) or one specific with [`ini_get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php).

Comment: auto_prepend_file and auto_append_file both have no values set at phpinfo...please check question for edits

Answer (score 1):

You don't see error because output buffering enabled. Try this code:

```
<?php
ob_end_clean();
?>
Text output already sent
<?php
header('Location: test2.php');
die();
?>
```

It return error:

> Text output already sent Warning: Cannot modify header information -
>   headers already sent by

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal try add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` into begin of this file

Answer (score 1):

You can check if and **where** headers have been sent with [headers_sent](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-sent.php) function:

```
if (!headers_sent($filename, $linenum)) {
    header('Location: test2.php');
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'Headers sent from '. $filename;
}
```

Then check the `$filename`.